# How to deal with frame by queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, video, queue

I push frame to queue, then use another thread to deal with it, but always run in "the push frame thread".

```
VideoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame;
private void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
    if (_fileWriter.IsOpen&&IsRecording)
    {
        _bitmaps.Enqueue(bitmap);
        //Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

but if I process Thread.Sleep(10), the another thread will work.

another thread code:

```
new Task(() =>
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    while (IsRecording==true)
    {
        if (_bitmaps.Count == 0)
            continue;
        _bitmaps.TryDequeue(out bitmap);
        if(bitmap!=null&& _fileWriter.IsOpen)
            _fileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap);
        if (_bitmaps.Count == 0 && IsRecording == false&&_fileWriter.IsOpen)
        {
            _fileWriter.Flush();
            _fileWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}).Start();
```

How to use more elegant method deal with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "always run in the push frame thread"?

Comment: @Kevin Gosse: the "while loop code" in the task will be executed no more three times.but the count is not zero.

Comment: Why are you creating `Task` with a constructor? It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change code to this.
it work...

```
var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```